# No me realiza el evento .on de jquery

Tags: php, jquery, php5

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy cargando un código desde **Php** hacia **html** con **jquery**. Lo que me esta sucediendo es que desde el código que estoy imprimiendo desde **Php** cuando me lo muestra en el html no me reconoce el jquery selector (**a.deleteComec**) que estoy imprimiendo desde **Php**. 
A continuación les dejo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar. 
Gracias.

**Código de Php**

```
        foreach ($datos as $val){ 
            if($usuario == $val['idusuario']){ 
            echo '<div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" >'.$val['nombre']." ".$val['fechahora'].'<div class="text-right"><a class="deleteComec" id="'.$val['id'].'" href="#" title="Borrar">Borrar</a></div></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">'. 
                        $val['comentario']
                .'</div>
            </div>';

            }else{ 

            echo '<div class="panel panel-warning ">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" >'.$val['nombre']." ".$val['fechahora'].'<div class="text-right"><a class="deleteComec" id="'.$val['id'].'" href="#" title="Borrar">Borrar</a></div></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">'.
                     $val['comentario']
                .'<div>
            </div>'; 
            }
        }
```

**Carga del contenido hacia el html con jquery**

```
var cargarmensaje = function(){
    idcoment = $("input#id").val();  
    $.post("index.php?c=pendientes&f=getcomentario",{id: idcoment},function(data){
        $("#listcomentario").html( data );
    });  
}
```

**Donde se ejecuta el selector (a.deleteComec)**

```
$('a.deleteComec').on("click",function () {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    bootbox.confirm("Está eguro que desea borrar. Recuerde que al borrar, se eleminaran todos los datos asociados en Cascada", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            $("div#idloader").addClass("loader");
            $.post('index.php?c=' + a_id[1] + '&f=delComec', {id:id}, function (data) {
                cargarmensaje();    
                $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");                
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Como se muestra el código en el navegador**

```
<a class="deleteComec" id="144" href="#" title="Borrar">Borrar</a>
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué usas PHP para eso? ¿Qué es lo que está en el servidor y no en el cliente para que tengas que usar PHP?

Comment: intenta modificar tu jquery de esta manera :  $(document).on('click', "a.class", function() {
    var liId = $(this).attr("id");
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento, esto sucede por el orden en que se asocian los eventos a los elementos dinamicos.
Lo que podrías hacer es refrescar el *listenner*, primeros quitando los *handlers* y luego los ReAsocias

```
function RefreshEventsListener() {
   //quitamos
    $("#listcomentario .a.deleteComec").off(); 

    //ReAsociamos
    $("#listcomentario .a.deleteComec").on("click", function() {
       //tu codigo
    }
}
```

Luego a esta función la puedes agregar cuando creas necesario.
 Por defecto en el `$(document).ready`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
    RefreshEventsListener();
 });
```

O cuando creas que se agregan mas elementos a esa clase por ejemplo un ajax

```
var cargarmensaje = function(){
    idcoment = $("input#id").val();  
    $.post("index.php?c=pendientes&f=getcomentario",{id: idcoment},function(data){
        $("#listcomentario").html( data );
    //Asociamos los eventos
  RefreshEventsListener();
    });  
}
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `.on()` solo funciona en elementos existentes y no directamente en elementos dinamicos.  Intenta cambiar tu selector a esto:

```
$('#listcomentario').on('click', 'a.deleteComec', function() {
```